# Warning when trying to initialize a 2D struct array with two initializer lists

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization, compiler-warnings

I am trying to initialize a 2D array of user defined type to zero by using following line,

```
qmf_t X_hybrid_left[32][32] = {{0}};
```

Where `qmf_t` is a user defined type. Here I get the compiler warning,

> warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]"

But if I use, `qmf_t X_hybrid_left[32][32] = {{{0}}};`, i.e. 3 braces each side, warning disappears.

Is it correct to use three braces on each side? What does it mean?

Comment: In this case I'd just suppress the warning and write the code as `{0}` which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
qmf_t X_hybrid_left[32][32] = {  /* Row initializers next */
                                { /* Col initializers next */
                                  { /* Struct initializers next */
                                     0
                                  }
                                }
                              };
qmf_t a = {0};
qmf_t b[5] = {{0}};
qmf_t c[10][5] = {{{0}}};
```

From C11 specs, **6.7.9 Initialization** grammar

> *initializer:
>
>       assignment-expression
>
>       { initializer-list }
>
>       { initializer-list , }*

Although in your particular case (zeroing all objects of 2 arrays), `qmf_t X_hybrid_left[32][32] = {0};` will work same as `qmf_t X_hybrid_left[32][32] = {{{0}}};` but compiler may warn you.

But if you want any non-zero initialization, you need to use multiple braces.

From the same section:

> [16] Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or
>   union type shall be a **brace enclosed list** of **initializers** for the
>   elements or named members.
>
> [20] If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are
>   aggregates or unions, these rules apply **recursively** to the
>   subaggregates or contained unions. If the initializer of a
>   subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the
>   initializers enclosed by that brace and its matching right brace
>   initialize the elements or members of the subaggregate or the
>   contained union. Otherwise, only enough initializers from the list are
>   taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate or
>   the first member of the contained union; any remaining initializers
>   are left to initialize the next element or member of the aggregate of
>   which the current subaggregate or contained union is a part.